# rsync: colon in file names

Tags: rsync, filenames

Other than by renaming the files first, how can I `rsync` files that may have colons in their names?

Comment: Make sure you are using `dir/` and not `dir/*` in rsync arguments.

Comment: The problem happens when I *rsync* from a hard drive to a flash memory stick: `rsync: mkstemp "/media/verd/rence/.Using an expressive work: fact or fiction.pdf.RbjlKK" failed: Invalid argument (22)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/verd/rence/.What's in a concept: structural foundations for semantic networks.pdf.tLXoZz" failed: Invalid argument (22)`

Comment: For future readers, please also note that this is filesystem dependent: Windows-typical hard drives with NTFS cannot contain files with `:` in the first place

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Colons are only special in the first directory component of a command line argument. So if you have what looks like a relative path, prepend `./`.

```
$ mkdir sou:rce
$ rsync -a sou:rce/ de:st/
The source and destination cannot both be remote.
$ rsync -av ./sou:rce/ ./de:st/
sending incremental file list
created directory ./de:st
./
```

In a script:

```
case $source in
  /*) :;;
  *) source=./$source;;
esac
case $dest in
  /*) :;;
  *) dest=./$dest;;
esac
rsync "$source" "$dest"
```

Comment: Thank you, Guilles. The problem happens when I *rsync* from a hard drive to a flash memory stick: `rsync: mkstemp "/media/verd/rence/.Using an expressive work: fact or fiction.pdf.RbjlKK" failed: Invalid argument (22)
rsync: mkstemp "/media/verd/rence/.What's in a concept: structural foundations for semantic networks.pdf.tLXoZz" failed: Invalid argument (22)`

Comment: @Kejia柯嘉: Ah, ok, your problem is to rename-and-rsync, not to pass the colons to rsync. This question came up before on the Ubuntu site: [How can I substitute colons when I rsync on a USB key?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/11634/how-can-i-substitute-colons-when-i-rsync-on-a-usb-key) Unfortunately no one's produced a satisfying answer.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' How does rsync know, with `rsync src ./hello@b.com:/test/`, if the dest is SSH or local? Here it could be both. Your answer states that prepending `./` makes rsync be sure it's a local path. But it's not 100% sure: `./hello` is a valid Linux username (I just tried with `useradd`). **TL;DR**: how to rsync with a *remote* with username `./hello`, host `b.com`, and path `/test/`?

Comment: @Basj I don't think rsync supports user names containing `/`. If you're using SSH for transport, I think you can use an `ssh_config` `Host` block with a `User` directive. Note that rsync is likely not the only program that doesn't support `/` in user names. [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) only allows ASCII letters, digits and `-_.`. Debian `adduser` only allows this and `@` (which surprises me because a lot of programs don't support `@` in user names!).

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' It would make sense indeed. `adduser a/b` gives `adduser: To avoid problems, the username should consist only of
letters, digits, underscores, periods, at signs and dashes, and not start with
a dash (as defined by IEEE Std 1003.1-2001). For compatibility with Samba
machine accounts $ is also supported at the end of the username.`. I should have tried this first instead of `useradd`!

Comment: PS: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' maybe you can add your last comment in the answer for future reference (these long comments will probably be cleaned in the future).