# find and rsync both choke on oddly named file

Tags: find, rsync, ls, filenames

This isn't an important issue to me, but I thought rsync and find were fairly robust, so I was surprised when rsync choked on a file, and then find did too. `ls -l` shows the file has 6093 bytes (and it's the only file in that directory that does, so I did this after cd'ing to that directory):

```
# find . -size 6093c
./????????????????????????:??????????????????????????????????????????
find: './\353\266\204\353\245\230:\353\257\270\352\265\255\354\235\230_\355\205\224\353\240\210\353\271\204\354\240\204_\352\262\214\354\236\204_\354\207\274': No such file or directory
```

Any idea what this means? Bizarrely,

```
# find . -size 6093c | xargs less
```

works fine. Here's what ls sees:

```
# ls -lat | fgrep "6093 "
ls: cannot access ''$'\353\266\204\353\245\230'':'$'\353\257\270\352\265\255\354\235\230''_'$'\355\205\224\353\240\210\353\271\204\354\240\204''_'$'\352\262\214\354\236\204''_'$'\354\207\274': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nobody nobody   6093 Oct 23  2013 à¸«à¸¡à¸§à¸à¸«à¸¡à¸¹à¹:à¹à¸à¸¡à¹à¸à¸§à¹à¸­à¹à¸¡à¸£à¸´à¸à¸²
```

It gets only slightly better if I pipe the results to less:

```
# ls -lat | fgrep "6093 " | less

ls: cannot access ''$'\353\266\204\353\245\230'':'$'\353\257\270\352\265\255\354\235\230''_'$'\355\205\224\353\240\210\353\271\204\354\240\204''_'$'\352\262\214\354\236\204''_'$'\354\207\274': No such file or directory
-rw-rw-r--. 1 nobody nobody   6093 Oct 23  2013 <E0><B8><AB><E0><B8><A1><E0><B8><A7><E0><B8><94><E0><B8><AB><E0><B8><A1><E0><B8><B9><E0><B9><88>:<E0><B9><80>
<E0><B8><81><E0><B8><A1><E0><B9><82><E0><B8><8A><E0><B8><A7><E0><B9><8C><E0><B8><AD><E0><B9><80><E0><B8><A1><E0><B8><A3><E0><B8><B4><E0><B8><81><E0><B8><B2>
```

The same directory has a file even ls can't handle, but I can list it since it kind of sort of shows up as the oldest entry:

```
# ls -lat | tail -1 | less
ls: cannot access ''$'\353\266\204\353\245\230'':'$'\353\257\270\352\265\255\354\235\230''_'$'\355\205\224\353\240\210\353\271\204\354\240\204''_'$'\352\262\214\354\236\204''_'$'\354\207\274': No such file or directory
-?????????? ? ?      ?           ?            ? <EB><B6><84><EB><A5><98>:<EB>
<AF><B8><EA><B5><AD><EC><9D><98>_<ED><85><94><EB><A0><88><EB><B9><84><EC><A0>
<84>_<EA><B2><8C><EC><9E><84>_<EC><87><BC>
```

Not super important, but sort of a curiosity.

EDIT: since this question seems have to drawn a lot of attention quickly, I did a little "research" (which may or may not be entirely accurate). I was not quite able to replicate the issue, but:

- On or near 23 Oct 2013, I visited the wikidata.org page on American Game Shows. At that time, it looked like this: https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?title=Q7213876&direction=prev&oldid=85645107
- I then followed one or more of the foreign language links.
- On the foreign links I followed, I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DownThemAll! to download all the links.
- Doing this yields many filenames with special characters, and I'm almost sure that's how I got these two weird files.
- However, doing that today, I still get filenames with special characters, but not quite the ones below.

Comment: What happens if you disable locales, i.e. run `LC_ALL=C find . -size 6093c` and similar?

Comment: My LC_ALL is already set to "C" (I was having problems with `sort` and this was the easiest way to solve them).

Comment: This is not consistent with the output of `ls -lat | fgrep "6093 "` above.

Comment: I just did "echo $LC_ALL" and got back "C" (I'm using tcsh) and that is what I'm getting. Should I screenshot instead of cut and paste?

Answer (score 1):

The oddly named file might be a red herring. Your tools are performing several tricks to make you think something is broken.

The filename is in UTF-8, so you should `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to allow your commands to use the filename without friction. Run the `locale` command with no arguments to verify the current environment variables.

Or, if you insist on using "C" locale, use `ls -b` to have ls print escape sequences instead of question marks. Then you can use `$'\353\266\204\…'` as an argument in bash.

The `find` command cowardly refuses to write non-textual characters to a tty. In other words, `find` and `find | cat` behave differently, with the latter writing the names unquoted, so that's why `find | xargs` is indeed working. A more robust way to write that is `find -print0 | xargs -0` to prevent possible whitespace characters from being interpreted by xargs.

This doesn't explain the "No such file or directory" — by all means, your filesystem may indeed contain an error — but it should allow you to state your intent to the command line more precisely.

At first I did not think it was relevant, but I am in the habit of prefixing strange file names with `./` to prevent commands from interpreting them. The sidebar showed a related question ["rsync: colon in file names"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/rsync-colon-in-file-names) which might be the root cause of your rsync error.