# How does rsync distinguish between destination being a local directory with ':' and '@' in the dirname, or a remote SSH?

Tags: ssh, rsync, directory, path

Technically, we could create a local directory called `user@example.com:` (it's a valid UNIX path, isn't it?), so how does `rsync` internally know if:

```
rsync test/ user@example.com:/test/
```

means:

- the destination is the **local** path `user@example.com:/test/` (i.e. `./user@example.com:/test/`)
- the destination is a remote host `user@example.com:/test/`

?

Out of curiosity, what is the decision rule that `rsync` uses?

Comment: It seems to be from https://github.com/AndyA/rsync/blob/master/options.c#L2707 to the end of this file, but I don't really see how it goes.

Comment: @roaima it helps but an analysis of the underlying rule (from source) would be interesting. I'll do it later (I posted in case someone already did it).

Comment: Empirically, it's "if the first path component matches `[user@]host:remote`, then treat it as remote", which is why prefixing a first element of a local path that also matches this with `./` solves the dilemma

Comment: @roaima how do we recognise it matches this? In terms of regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite complicated.

The solution suggested in [rsync: colon in file names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11581/rsync-colon-in-file-names) seems to work in general, but there are lots of possible corner cases.

Example: how does rsync know, with `rsync src ./hello@b.com:/test/`, if the dest is remote or local?
It could be a local path `./hello@b.com:/test/` with `:` and `@` in the directory name.
Or it could be a remote with username `./hello` (strange Unix username, but possible! try it with `useradd`!), host `b.com`, and path `/test/`.

[Here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/816036f142ecd284c12bb3685ae316a68d2ef190/misc.c#L882) is the code that parses URI in OpenSSH's `scp` implementation, and it's worth reading it.

The rules are explained in the IETF draft https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-scp-sftp-ssh-uri-04